# How to print bar code from Microsoft PowerApp

Tags: powerapps, powerapps-canvas

I'm working on a PowerApp which need to generate and print the barcodes. Currently, I've generated barcodes using web API which is returning me the barcode as a PNG image. Now, need to print this barcode from printer. I search much on this and couldn't find the solution yet , I found some posts like https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/PowerApps-Ideas/Printing/idi-p/846 , saying that printing is not available now. But, it is a old post, I need the latest update on printing and when it will be available. Also please let me know any other way around to achieve printing from the PowerApp, so I could instantly print the barcodes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its not a way to **directly** print, but you could:

- Use Flow to call the barcode API and convert the .png to .pdf using the [OneDrive Actions](https://us.flow.microsoft.com/en-us/galleries/public/templates/0ffc6d1b79ea481bbbc820df7273f303/convert-a-file-to-pdf-using-onedrive-for-business/)
- Use Flow to call the bacrcode API and convert the .png to .pnf then email it to user so they can print.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

**Printing using pdf - But with more customization:**

> I'm using this to Tag Packets of Timber.

In Power Flow:

1. Use Onedrive Upload file from URL to fetch your barcode:
   `https://barcode.tec-it.com/barcode.ashx?data=MY_PACK_NUMBER&code=EANUCC128&height=20&hidehrt=True`
   [image: Onedrive Upload file from URL]
2. Get file content of image & Uri Encode it:
   [image: Flow Get file and encode using dataUri]
   `dataUri(outputs('Get_file_content')?['body'])`
   [image: Code for converting image to Uri]
3. Using HTML, Craft the label:
   [image]

   ```html
   <div style='font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;height: 101.6mm;width:152.4mm;border-style: solid;overflow: hidden;'>

     <h1 style='font-size:50px;padding:10px;margin:0px;text-align: center;'>@{triggerBody()['text']}</h1>
     <img style='position:left;padding-left:50px' src="@{outputs('ImageEncoded')}" />
     <p style='padding-left:10px;font-size:40px;margin:0px;padding-top:10px;'>@{triggerBody()['text_1']}</p>
     <br>
     <table style='font-weight:bold;width:100%;padding:10px;border:none;margin-left: 10px;'>
       <tr>
         <td>LM:</td>
         <td>258.92</td>
         <td>M3:</td>
         <td>1.139</td>
         <td>13 Jan 22</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
         <td>Tally:</td>
         <td colspan="3">1/1.52 12/1.83 4/2.13 93/2.44</td>
       </tr>
     </table>
   </div>
   ```

   Here is what my template looks like from the HTML above:
   [image: Preview of HTML tag template]

> You could stop here and convert the HTML to PDF using Onedrive or a
> paid Service, But I need a Landscape PDF of a particular size for my
> Label Printer.

1. Save HTML to file, Then Convert HTML to JPG:
   [image]
2. Create a MS Word Fillable Template to accept inputs from our flow:

   HowTo:  [Guide to Create fillable Form in Word for use in Flow](https://tahoeninjas.blog/2020/03/13/generate-word-documents-from-a-template-using-power-automate/)

> Only First Section of linked guide is needed

I've changed the margins on my page, Added a single Picture content control, Changed to Landscape and added and resized sample image to match:

[image: Adding Image Control to Word Template]

It would be best to give the Control a Name, I didn't:
[image]

1. Save template in Onedrive, (mine is saved under /PDF)
2. In Flow: Populate Template, Save it as new docx file then Convert to PDF:
   [image: Populate word template, save then convert to PDF]
3. Lastly: Save your PDF:
   [image: Save PDF to Drive]
   End Result: - Landscape PDF, Custom Size with Barcode.
   [image: End result]

   I then submit this PDF to PrintNode API to get printed: - Tutorial: [Print Using PrintNode](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=m4Fu9af2h1c&ab_channel=ShaneYoung)
   [image: PrintNode Example]

    - Note: It takes about 10 seconds to run this flow.

Comment: PS: Only did the extra converting HTML to JPG step to overcome MS Word Template Limitation of having fixed Image Sizes, the Dynamix size of Barcodes always gets warped if attempting to do entire process through Word Templates alone.

Comment: The link to the fillable forms in Word isn't working. I really like how you did this and want to follow it. Is there an updated link you can provide?